# Reference on internal categories and externalization

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, internal-categories

I'm looking for a reference on internal categories and externalization of internally defined notions.

The nlab has a stub on [externalization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/externalization) (more details are available under [small fibration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/small+fibration)) and the page on [internal categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category) gives enough of an introduction that I can sketch most internal notions, but I could really use a concise introduction to internal categories and externalization, and if possible the relationship between internalization and externalization. Are they adjoint in some sense?

I'm fine assuming a background of $2$-category theory, so talking about the $2$-category of internal categories in a category with pullbacks etc. would make sense, but ideally the reference would assume no familiarity with internal category theory or externalization. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think such a reference exists. As observed in the abstract of [these notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.02927), much of the foundational work of Bénabou on fibred categories is unpublished. But perhaps you might start by reading those notes, and maybe chapter B2 of _Sketches of an elephant_.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you, I’ll take a look at those notes. My uni library is currently closed (and doesn’t have a copy to boot), and I don’t have half a g to drop on Sketches right now — are you aware of anywhere I can access that portion online?

Comment: I don't think Johnstone has made any part of the Elephant online. Personally I'm holding out for volume 3 (and a corrected edition of the first two volumes) before buying a personal copy...

Comment: @ZhenLin Cest la vie, that's a good idea anyway -- I'll see if any nearby universities or public libraries have copies available on request.

Comment: I would try Bart Jacobs' book _Categorical logic and type theory_. It has a very good intro to fibred categories and internal categories and the relation between them.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Will do, thank you; for any interested parties, the book David mentions can be found here: https://people.mpi-sws.org/~dreyer/courses/catlogic/jacobs.pdf.

Comment: @Alec good find. Also, PTJ once handed out **paper** versions of a preprint at a talk of his I attended. Putting his magnum opus online is a much more extreme option than just using the arXiv like a normal person.

Comment: @AlecRhea: Johnstone's Sketches of an Elephant is available here: http://libgen.rs/book/index.php?md5=22AECD1E74BE933CBA966B1396122B77

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Excellent, thank you! (I still intend to buy a copy eventually, for the record)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For what it's worth, I should add my comment as an answer. Chapter 1 of Bart Jacobs' book *Categorical logic and type theory* (Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics **141** (1999), ([author's page](http://www.cs.ru.nl/B.Jacobs/CLT/bookinfo.html), [publisher page](https://www.elsevier.com/books/categorical-logic-and-type-theory/jacobs/978-0-444-50170-7), [pdf](https://people.mpi-sws.org/%7Edreyer/courses/catlogic/jacobs.pdf))) is a good intro to fibred category theory, and chapter 7 has an intro to internal category theory, and it links the two. Chapter 9 does some more advanced fibred category theory.

Comment: This ended up being exactly what I was looking for; I’ll have to learn about the internal logic of fibrations to fully understand what he’s saying, but that topic is also covered earlier on. Thank you!