# Externalisation for non-Cartesian internal categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, internal-categories

In the context of category theory internal  to a category $(\mathcal{E},\times,\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{E}})$ with pullbacks and a terminal object, the process of [externalisation](https://mathoverflow.net/q/372040) builds an indexed category $\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{C}}\colon\mathcal{E}^{\mathsf{op}}\to\mathsf{Cats}_{\mathsf{2}}$ from an $\mathcal{E}$-internal category $\mathcal{C}$, defining a $2$-functor
$$
\mathbb{E}
\colon
\mathsf{Cats}_{\mathcal{E}}
\longrightarrow
\mathsf{PseudoFun}(\mathcal{E}^{\mathsf{op}},\mathsf{Cats}_{\mathsf{2}})
$$
from the $2$-category of $\mathcal{E}$-internal categories to the $2$-category of $\mathcal{E}$-indexed categories.

When one replaces $(\mathcal{E},\times,\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{E}})$ by a monoidal category $(\mathcal{V},\otimes_{\mathcal{V}},\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{V}})$, one can still define internal categories to $\mathcal{V}$, provided $\mathcal{V}$ is regular. This is the subject of [Aguiar's PhD thesis](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Emaguiar/thesis2.pdf), where the notion is defined and studied.

**Question:** Can one define externalisation for categories internal to $\mathcal{V}$?

Comment: (I also asked this question on [Zulip](https://categorytheory.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/229136-theory.3A-category.20theory/topic/Externalisation.20of.20non-Cartesian.20internal.20categories))

Comment: After browsing briefly through the linked article: Is there any way to view arbitrary objects in $\mathcal E$ as internal categories (over the identity comonoid)? Maybe this would give you some functor $\mathcal E \to \mathsf{Int_\mathcal E}$ that you could compose with the functor $[-, \mathcal F]:\mathcal C\mapsto[\mathcal C, \mathcal F]$ where $[\mathcal C, \mathcal F]$ is the internal functor category.

Comment: @Emily May I ask you how one gets invited to that Zulip chat?

Comment: @GerritBegher I think this gives the monoids in $\mathcal{V}$: letting $\mathcal{C}_{0}=(\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{V}},\lambda^{\mathcal{V}}_{\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{V}}},\mathrm{id}_{\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{V}}})$, makes $\mathcal{C}_{1}$ have the trivial $(\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{V}},\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{V}})$-bicomodule structure via the left/right unitor maps. Then composition...

Comment: ...for $\mathcal{C}$ is a map from
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{C}_{1}\boxtimes_{\mathcal{C}_{0}}\mathcal{C}_{1} &\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=} \mathcal{C}_{1}\boxtimes_{\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{V}}}\mathcal{C}_{1}\\
&\cong\mathcal{C}_{1}\otimes_{\mathcal{V}}\mathcal{C}_{1}
\end{align*}
$$
to $\mathcal{C}_{1}$, which gives us the monoid multiplication of $\mathcal{C}_{1}$. Meanwhile, the unit map $\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{V}}\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\mathcal{C}_{0}\to\mathcal{C}_{1}$ gives us the monoid unit, and then the $\mathcal{V}$-internal category axioms reduce to the $\mathcal{V}$-monoid ones.

Comment: (So this corresponds to the identification of one-object categories with monoids via the assignment $\mathcal{C}\mapsto\mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{C}}(\star)\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(\star,\star)$ when $\mathcal{V}=\mathsf{Sets}$)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg You can join using this [link](https://categorytheory.zulipchat.com/join/ff7oyoqe4tenl4oiywaubqpq/). Welcome to the category theory Zulip! :-)

Comment: @Emily Thanks! It worked.